# Php curl send xml file via SSL as GET method or Pt method

Tags: php, ssl, curl, methods, put

I need to receive xml data from server.
Allowed only two methods to send data to server "GET" AND "PUT"
POST method- is no allowed.

My code is

```
    <?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('display_errors','1');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url = 'https://url is here..';
    $fp = fopen(getcwd() . "/ping.xml", "r+");

// Initialize session and set URL.
    $ch = curl_init();

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?xml='.$xml); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    

    //GET
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize(getcwd() . "/ping.xml")); 


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3 );  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . "/certs/test_lv.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "test_lv");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . "/certs/test_lv.key");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "test_lv");

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','correlationId :'.date("y-m-d-h-m-s")));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    // Get the response and close the channel.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    print_r($response);
    echo '<br>end';
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I have spent all my day connecting to the server and now it works.
I trying to send xml file as Put method 
Xml file data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Ping>
<Value>Test</Value>
</Ping>
```

Its not work I have this error:

***HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Content-Length: 0 Server: Jetty(6.1.21)
end***

Answers needs to be:
Received pong.xml-s

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<B4B xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://test.net/valid/hgw-response.xsd">
<Pong from="EE">
<Value>Test</Value>
</Pong></B4B>
```

Thanks for advices

P.S How can i Send xml file via GET method ..Im trying to do this

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Ping>
            <Value>Test</Value>
        </Ping>';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?xml='.$xml);
```

It's not work too for me.